# Refresh Oracle and Spatialite Layer with PyQgis

Tags: qgis-3, spatialite, pyqgis-3, cx-oracle

I'm working on a Dockwidget with PyQgis.

I made an insert into an Oracle DB and a Spatialite DB and I would like to see the new insert (it's a point).

[image]

The Layer where the new point is add is URB_A_ADPT. I'm sure the point is create because I see it in my DB and attribute table. For now, when I zoom and dezoom the point appears but I would like to see it directly.

I tried to simply add

```
self.refresh = self.canvas.refreshAllLayers()
```

but it don't seems to be enough to refresh my Oracle layer.

I also tried

```
if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
    layer.triggerRepaint()
else:
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

from the idea of @andreas-müller but once again I don't see anything.

And my last idee was to set zoom and then directly dezoom

```
active_layer = iface.activeLayer()
active_layer.zoomFull()
active_layer.zoomToPrevious()
```

but it don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
    layer.triggerRepaint()
else:
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

This one is from the [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html), and as mentioned there, it should refresh the query from your database, too.
I added a layer-access by iface.activeLayer(), but it could be any method to get a reference to the layer which needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Finally, I was able to use the ```layer.triggerRepaint()``` but I didn't know how to specify the layer, I needed : ```layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer_name")[0]
layer.triggerRepaint()``` , but I don't use the Oracle DB for the visual anymore, Spatialite goes faster. Also I didn't need ```isCachingEnabled()``` and ```iface.mapCanvas().refresh()```. If you edit your answer with the definition of the layer (and maybe without "if else" but not sure (?) ) I will accept it !

Comment: Also, should I edit my question only for Spatialite because I didn't try to use Oracle again ? ( and Thank you for the help by the way !)

Comment: this could be usefull, but the problem with the Oracle-DB may also be important. Because Oracle is really complex, it would be an idea to ask that question in another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

For Spatialite:

It works when I specify the layer and set auto refresh:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("my_layer_name")[0] 
layer.setAutoRefreshInterval(500)
layer.setAutoRefreshEnabled(True)
```

For Oracle it takes too much time for the visual part, so I interact with spatialite in QGis, but I make my SQL statements on the two DB in parallel.

Comment: Auto Refresh was a temporary solution, but it takes a lot of memory, I don't recommend it with big database (such as mine) !